# How many "rows data" that are "too many" for the html table

Tags: html, datatables, ng-grid

Ok, I asked this before, got down voted and everyone told me to paginate. But now, I know the issue.

I have a project that has about 500 rows of data and uses `DataTables`. It lags at the start but searches super fast. It's even faster than server side processing.

Another project has 20,000 rows of data and it makes my client's computer hang every time to render it.

Why not paginate it at the server? Well, because it is harder. The data sent to the client is already filtered. Using complicated logic like

```
where columnA = 1 and columnB = 2 or ColumnC = 3.
```

And we are using an ORM. So we have some obstacles in a trying to group "where" with "and" and "or". And if we send the search query we add the more complicated

```
columnD like "%asd%" or columnE like "%asd%" and columnF like "%asd"
```

to the query. With too many logical conditions at the server, it is hard to get it right.

I think responsibility separation between server and client are the best way to do this development. It's like server said to client

> Ok, I filtered "columnA", "columnB" and "columnC". Now if you want to search in "columnD", "columnE" and "columnF" do it your self.

So forgive me if I'm too dumb to ask for your experience about how many rows that you think are too many for an html table (either with a plugin or not).

Comment: What's the point of your question? What you want to know that limit for? Suppose everyone tell you that the maximum tolerable number of rows is 1000. What would you do with that figure?

Comment: I asked this because I'm woried about the performance of web application that I've been developed right now. If they said 1000 is tolerable number, I will say, we will dicuss it again when it reach 800 rows data or so.

Answer (score 3):

Well after researching the net, I got some number that the plugin provide.

Angular UI Grid claims it can perform with large datasets call it 10,000+ rows

http://ui-grid.info/

DataTables claim about 5,000 rows in form of table, 50,000 from ajax sourced serverside is only needed when we want to process more than a million rows.

http://datatables.net/faqs/#General-initialisation

I had an experiments with d3 js with more that 2.4MB data in json. It hold more than 20,000 unstructure data. So when it come to performance maybe there are some conclusion.

I think 1,000 rows of table in html table is not that much. browser can render it althouth it a litle bit slow at first. Remember it is wised to do some client paginated processed. Because althout browser can render it, human can't consume it really well.

It also better seperate your data and your presentation. You don't have to do some server processing. It will make more request when the data are too small. And more request is more lag in your browser. With source data and keep it in memory, your browser doesn't have render it quickly, but have in memory to search quickly.

Comment: Yes, I've developedJSP webpages (some 10 years ago) with 1000 rows and 25+ columns, and it rendered quite well (pure HTML rendering, no javascript). And most important is that you said yourself: A hugh figure of rows would not be readable for a human. But at the end, you'd better test your page's performance yourself through a volume test.